# Вывод связанных данных из Django в Drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch

Гайз, застакался в вопросе и нужна помощь
Есть бэк на django
Как вы видите таблицы education и experience связаны с таблицей person. И я в drf пытаюсь вывести все эти связанные данные таким образом, чтобы в объекте person были  объекты experience и education, но так как person в себе не хранит ссылки ни на education, ни на experience, у меня это сделать не получается(Я могу вывести объект person в объектах experience и education, а наоборот не получается). Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть, буду благодарен любой помощи.

Вот модель данных models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """
    Our general model
    """
    person_hash_index = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, db_index=True)  # country
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    last_position = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, db_index=True)
    current_company = models.CharField(max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, db_index=True)
    event_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    total_duration = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0, null=True, db_index=True)
    updated = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Absolute url for our template
        :return: redirect to person_view page
        """
        return reverse('person_view', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Education(models.Model):
    """
    Person education table
    This table are inherited from Person table
    """
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person_education')
    edu_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, null=False)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=65000, blank=True)
    admission_date = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    graduation_date = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (
            self.university, self.degree, self.info, self.admission_date, self.graduation_date
        )


class Experience(models.Model):
    """
    Person Experience table
    This table are inherited from Person table
    """
    exp_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, null=False)
    person = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='KeyRelationExp', related_name='person_experience')
    person_relation = models.ForeignKey('Person',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True, null=True,
                                        related_name='person_relation_experience')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    hiring_date = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fired_date = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    job_location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=65535, blank=True)
    duration = models.FloatField()  # mb datetime
    exp_index = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (
            self.company, self.position, self.hiring_date, self.fired_date, self.job_location, self.description
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['exp_id']


class Comments(models.Model):
    """
    User comment
    This table are inherited from Person table
    """
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
                               related_name='person_comments')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['publish']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.name}'


class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    person = models.ManyToManyField('Person',
                                    through='KeyRelationPerson',
                                    related_name='person_keyword')
    experience = models.ManyToManyField('Experience', through='KeyRelationExp', related_name='person_keyword_experience')
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword


class Area(models.Model):
    keyword_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    person = models.ManyToManyField('Person',
                                    through='KeyRelationPerson',
                                    related_name='person_area')
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword


class KeyRelationPerson(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    keyword = models.ForeignKey('Keyword', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    tag_order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class KeyRelationExp(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    exp = models.ForeignKey('Experience', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    keyword = models.ForeignKey('Keyword', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    tag_order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Вот мой код serializers.py

```
from .models import Person, Experience, Education, Keyword, Area
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.serializers import DocumentSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .documents import PersonDocument


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'


class EducationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person_id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    person = PersonSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = '__all__'


class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        fields = '__all__'


class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Area
        fields = '__all__'


class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields = '__all__'


class PersonDocumentSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        document = PersonDocument
        fields = [
            'person_hash_index',
            'surname',
            'url',
            'location',
            'city',
            'last_position',
            'current_company',
            'event',
            'event_date',
            'total_duration',
            'updated',
        ]
```

Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.constants import (
    LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_CONTAINS,
    LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
    SUGGESTER_COMPLETION
)
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.filter_backends import (
    FilteringFilterBackend,
    SearchFilterBackend,   # CompoundSearchFilterBackend should to use cause SearchFilterBackend is deprecated
    SuggesterFilterBackend
)
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.viewsets import DocumentViewSet
from .models import *
from .documents import PersonDocument


class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    queryset = Person.objects.all()


class ExperienceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ExperienceSerializer
    queryset = Experience.objects.all()


class EducationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EducationSerializer
    queryset = Education.objects.all()


class KeywordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer
    queryset = Keyword.objects.all()


class AreaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AreaSerializer
    queryset = Area.objects.all()


class PersonSearch(APIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    document_class = PersonDocument

    def generate_q_expression(self, query):
        return Q('match', name={'query': query})

    def get(self, request, query):
        q = self.generate_q_expression(query)
        search = self.document_class.search().query(q)
        return Response(self.serializer_class(search.to_queryset(), many=True).data)


class PersonDocumentViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    document = PersonDocument
    serializer_class = PersonDocumentSerializer

    filter_backends = (FilteringFilterBackend, SearchFilterBackend, SuggesterFilterBackend)  # CompoundSearchFilterBackend should to use cause SearchFilterBackend is deprecated
    search_fields = ('first_name',)
    filter_fields = {
        'location': {
            'field': 'location',
            'lookups': [LOOKUP_QUERY_IN]   # ?location__in=russia, ?location__in=russia__germany
        },
        'city': {
            'field': 'city',
            'lookups': [LOOKUP_QUERY_IN]
        },
        'last_position': {
            'field': 'last_position',
            'lookups': [LOOKUP_QUERY_IN]
        },
        'current_company': {
            'field': 'current_company',
            'lookups': [LOOKUP_QUERY_IN]
        },
        'event': {
            'field': 'event',
            'lookups': [LOOKUP_QUERY_IN]
        },
        'total_duration': {
            'field': 'total_duration',
            'lookups': [LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE, LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE, LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE]  # total_duration_gte=5, total_duration_lte=5, total_duration_range=5__7
        }

    }

    suggester_fields = {
        'first_name_suggest': {
            'field': 'first_name.suggest',
            'suggesters': [SUGGESTER_COMPLETION]
        }
    }
```

Фронтеенд на React, так же использую Elasticsearch, как поисковой движок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя прописан аргумент **related_name** в обоих моделях. Через него и обращаешься к связанным записям.

Из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

> The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this
> one. It’s also the default value for related_query_name (the name to
> use for the reverse filter name from the target model). See the
> related objects documentation for a full explanation and example. Note
> that you must set this value when defining relations on abstract
> models; and when you do so some special syntax is available.
>
> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set
> related_name to '+' or end it with '+'. For example, this will ensure
> that the User model won’t have a backwards relation to this model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='+',
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, по вашей наводке переписал как мне было нужно
```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    experiences_list = ExperienceSerializer(source='person_relation_experience', many=True, read_only=True)
    education_list = EducationSerializer(source='person_education', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет переписать serializer подобным образом:

```
class EducationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = '__all__'


class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        fields = '__all__'



class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    experience = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    education = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [

            ...

            'experience',
            'education',
        ]

    def get_experience(self, obj):
        queryset = Experience.objects.filter(person=obj)
        return [ExperienceSerializer(q).data for q in queryset]

    def get_education(self, obj):
        queryset = Education.objects.filter(person=obj)
        return [EducationSerializer(q).data for q in queryset]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ